# PHP executing bash script using sudo not working

Tags: php, bash, centos, centos7

I am unable to run a bash script using sudo with the shell_exec() function in PHP. I get an error saying:

> Sorry, user apache is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash /var/www/html/private/createFTP.sh' as root on test.server.com.

PHP:

```
shell_exec('sudo bash /var/www/html/private/createFTP.sh 2>&1');
```

Visudo:

```
apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/private/createFTP.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If your web server is in chroot jail then that will cause this type of error. If you are running a chrooted server, make sure you mirror across your /etc/sudoers file to the jail filesystem too and adjust for the chroot directory structure when setting up sudoers file as well as your script will have moved once you are in chroot. Also check you have the sudo libraries and executable in the jail filesystem as well.

Comment: I believe you are right. It is in chroot jail because I am trying to generate sftp users for people who register to the site for a school project. If I am understanding correctly it is a permission issue?

Comment: When chrooted, your "root" changes to a subdirectory of your real system and the process running in the jail can't see files beyond what you have defined as root. So if a file in your system's full path is /a/b/c/somefile and you make a chroot jail at say b, then b becomes / (root) and the new path for somefile is /c/somefile to any process running in that chroot jail. If you put into sudoers that a user can execute file /a/b/c/somefile and you simply copy that to the (chroot)/etc/sudoers file then it will not find somefile because according to the jail instance, it's actually in /c/somefile.

Comment: That's a great explanation thank you. So copying sudoers there would not make a difference?